# Search values across all columns in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

Here's a sample data frame.

```
df = data.frame(company = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
                 bond = c(0.2, 1, 0.3, 0),
                 equity = c(0.7, 0, 0.5, 1),
                 cash = c(0.1, 0, 0.2, 0))
df

  company bond equity cash
1       a  0.2    0.7  0.1
2       b  1.0    0.0  0.0
3       c  0.3    0.5  0.2
4       d  0.0    1.0  0.0
```

I need to find companies which have 1.0 in any columns. 
The expected result should be **b and d**.

Please provide a solution that works for >20 columns. 
Solutions like `df %>% filter(bond == 1)` only works for searching a particular column.

`dplyr` or `data.table` solutions are acceptable.

Thanks.

Comment: Checking for equality with floats is an error-prone business, fyi. Try looking at `x  = (.1+.2)*(10/3)` and then testing `x==1`...

Comment: Fwiw, here are some variations on the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28233561/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/25692392/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rowSums` to check the logic data frame should work:

```
df[rowSums(df[-1] == 1.0) != 0, 'company']
[1] b d
Levels: a b c d
```

Comment: Btw, just aside...could you share how you would search for non-numeric columns?

Comment: Do you mean the filter condition is different for each column? I don't think this method will work for that case. Anyway you need to be more specific about what the columns and conditions are.

Answer (score 5):

We can also use `Reduce` with `==`

```
res <- df[Reduce(`+`, lapply(df[-1], `==`, 1))!=0,]
res
#   company bond equity cash
#2       b    1      0    0
#4       d    0      1    0

res$company
#[1] b d
#Levels: a b c d
```

Comment: I think the akrun way is `df[!!rowSums(df==1),]` :)

Comment: @PierreLafortune  Yes, you are right, but somebody already posted solution with `rowSums`, so I didn't want to get into a tussle about plagiarism :-)

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
df[unique(row(df[-1])[df[-1] == 1L]),]
#  company bond equity cash
#2       b    1      0    0
#4       d    0      1    0

df$company[unique(row(df[-1])[df[-1] == 1L])]
#[1] b d
#Levels: a b c d
```

Comment: @PierreLafortune - in this case, yep, but I think the unique is needed if there is a 1 in multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
var <- df %>% select(bond:cash) %>% names
plyr::ldply(var, function(x) paste("filter(df,", x, "==1)") %>% parse(text=.) %>% eval)
  company bond equity cash
1       b    1      0    0
2       d    0      1    0
```