# R: update a column value by checking other columns in the same row

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have the following data frame in R, and I need to update the values in column `feat_4` to 1 if any of the other 3 feature columns (feat_1, feat_2, and feat_3) contains a 1:

```
Name  feat_1  feat_2  feat_3   feat_4
Tom    0        0       0        0
David  1        0       1        0
Tim    0        1       0        0
```

I know I can do this by using a `for-loop` like this, but is there a more efficient/vectorized way of doing it? I could have more columns than what is being show above. Thank you for help!

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (any(df[row,2:4] == 1)) {
     df$feat_4 = 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate - `pmin(1, rowSums(dat[2:4]))` or something similar should do it.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233561/finding-rows-containing-a-value-or-values-in-any-column or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089453/search-values-across-all-columns-in-r-data-frame